# What happens if a shared_ptr's constructor fails?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

If I understand correctly, when a shared_ptr (from boost, tr1, std, whatever) is initialised with a pointer to a freshly-allocated object, the shared_ptr's constructor allocates a small amount of memory to hold a reference count for the pointer it manages.  What happens if that allocation fails?  In the following code:

```
class my_class {};
void my_func(shared_ptr<my_class> arg);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    my_func(shared_ptr<my_class>(new my_class()));
    return 0;
}
```

...will the `my_class` object be leaked if the shared_ptr fails to allocate memory for its reference count?  Or does shared_ptr's constructor take responsibility for deleting the object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will not leak the `my_class` object, even if `shared_ptr` could not allocate memory.

According to the C++11 standard (20.7.2.2.1), in the `shared_ptr` constructor:

> Throws: bad_alloc, or an implementation-deﬁned exception when a resource other than memory
>   could not be obtained.
>
> Exception safety: If an exception is thrown, delete p is called.

In the constructor version that takes a user-defined deleter, the deleter will be used instead.

[Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors) specifies the same.

Comment: Cheers.  I did fire up Google but didn't find an answer.  One of these days I'll learn to check the source - ie the standard.  :-)